# Bundler erase logger's format?

Tags: ruby, logging, activesupport

As long as I require gems by `Bundler.require`, my logger doesn't work well any more.

```
require "logger"
logger1 = Logger.new(STDERR)

require 'bundler/setup'
Bundler.require
logger2 = Logger.new(STDERR)

logger1.info 123
logger2.info 123
```

Output:

```
I, [2012-06-29T17:51:30.323356 #20774]  INFO -- : 123
123
```

I even don't have `logger` in my `Gemfile`.

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem "activesupport", "~> 3.2.6", :require => ["active_support", "active_support/core_ext"]
```

**EDIT**: 
seems the problem is from `ActiveSupport`. Could I have it and `Logger` both? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`active_support/core_ext` changes the default logger format to `Logger::SimpleFormatter`.

To get the old formatter back you just need to manually assign it after initialization:

```
logger2 = Logger.new(STDERR)
logger2.formatter = Logger::Formatter.new

logger2.info 123
=> I, [2012-06-29T13:56:07.580428 #24714]  INFO -- : 123
```